# raise event in UI thread

Tags: c#, winforms, compact-framework

I need to raise events in UI thread, all solution I have found are only for full framework: for example very simple solution with GetInvocationList and ISynchronizeInvoke, but NET CF does not support ISynchronizeInvoke. Is there any way to raise events in UI thread for CF? My code is below. I use .NET CF 3.5

```
class Publisher {
  public event EventHandler OnEventHandler;
  private void OnEvent()
  {
    var handler = OnEventHandler;
    if (handler != null) handler(this, EventArgs.Empty); 
  }
}
```

Comment: You'll have to pass a Control reference through the constructor so you can use its Invoke() method to raise the event.  It is certainly easier to just have the event subscriber deal with it.

Comment: Yes, I understand about Control reference, but I do not like this because Publisher knows nothing about UI, controls etc.In addition Views might be created after the Publisher created.

Comment: Right, that invokes the "it is certainly easier" clause.  This is not unprecedented, SerialPort raises events on another thread for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use `MethodInvoker`, which has to be declared (because it does not exist under the compact framework), then include a link to the parent control (usually the main form):

```
class Publisher {
  #if PocketPC // MethodInvoker delegate is not declared in CF!
  public delegate void MethodInvoker(); 
  #endif
  private Form _parent;

  public Publisher(Form parent) {
    _parent = parent;
  }

  public event EventHandler OnEventHandler;
  private void OnEvent() {
    if (OnEventHandler != null) {
      MethodInvoker mi = delegate { OnEventHandler(this, EventArgs.Empty); };
      try {
        _parent.BeginInvoke(methInvoker);
      } catch (ObjectDisposedException) {
      } catch (NullReferenceException err) {
        LogError("OnEvent NullReference", err);
      } catch (InvalidOperationException err) {
        LogError("OnEvent InvalidOperation", err);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Hopefully, you are able to do something with that. ;)

~Joe

Comment: Woops. I just read the comments you posted to Hans about not wanting the Publisher to subscribe to the events. Any votes to remove this answer or leave it here for others to gain from?

Comment: I understand that I need some instance of a control to use invoke methods. So now my Publisher can achieve that control and your solution works good. Thanks.